# Align select and input

Tags: html, css, alignment, label, fieldset

Is possible align SELECT and INPUT inline **without specify WIDTH** size, **without using tables** and with the **same HTML**? See picture.
Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/N4hpQ/
Thank you.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

fieldset {
display: inline-block;
}

fieldset input,
fieldset select{
float: right;
margin-left: 5px;   
}

fieldset p {
text-align: right;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<fieldset>          
<p><label>First Name: </label><input type="text" /></p>
<p><label>Second Name: </label><input type="text" /></p>
<p><label>Country: </label><select><option>Choose</option></select></p>
<p><label>Age: </label><select><option>Choose</option></select></p>
</fieldset> 

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: I believe this is one of the very, very seldom cases I would choose a `<table>` if no `width` is allowed. At least it is semantically more correct than `<p>`. Note that you're currently missing the `for=` attribute in your HTML. You can either include the right `<input>`/`<select>` in the label itself or you should add the attribute.

Comment: No width at all?  I can't think of a way, except by using a table as Zeta mentioned.  If with width, you could float the label and input/select to the left, and then apply "display: inline-block; text-align: right; width: 175px;" (or whatever width you need) to the label elements.

Comment: I give up here: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/N4hpQ/10/, not sure if it works at any browser different from chrome

Comment: No width at all, the text of LABEL is variable by coding. The capture is only an example.

Comment: @eicto Is possible align to left the fieldset?

Comment: @FeKuLa as i said i giveup here, because i don't found a way to do that usable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use css `display: table;` to achieve this.

**HTML**

```
<fieldset>
    <p>
        <label>First Name: </label>
        <input type="text" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Second Name: </label>
        <input type="text" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Country: </label>
        <select>
            <option>Choose</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Age: </label>
        <select>
            <option>Choose</option>
        </select>
    </p>
</fieldset>
​
```

**CSS**

```css
fieldset {
    display: table;
}
fieldset p {
    display: table-row;
}
fieldset input, 
fieldset select, 
fieldset label {
    display: table-cell;
    margin: 3px;
}
fieldset label {
    text-align: right;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W3B5S/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

Without `TABLE` or `width`.

CSS:

```
FIELDSET {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 200%;
}
.labels {
    text-align: right;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.inputs {
    float: left;
}
```

And HTML:

```
<fieldset>          
    <div class="labels">
        <label>First Name: </label><br />
        <label>Second Name: </label><br />
        <label>Country: </label><br />
        <label>Age: </label>
    </div>
    <div class="inputs">
        <input type="text" /><br />
        <input type="text" /><br />
        <select><option>Choose</option></select><br />
        <select><option>Choose</option></select>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

And the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RMwmV/2/)

---

**EDIT**

It seems that you've edited your question. If the same HTML (as in your example) is required, my answer is not valid anymore.

Comment: Using my HTML: <P><LABEL>TEXT</LABEL><INPUT TYPE="TEXT"></P> is not possible?

Comment: @FeKuLa I think you can use the CSS from eicto's fiddle. It uses relative unit (`%`) for width, hence it has only influence inside of the `fieldset`, and you can use any label text you want.

Answer (score 0):

Possible? Yes, here's a quick hack to do it even:

float your labels left, float your inputs right, then give the inputs a margin-right, to put them in position to be next to your labels.

so would look like this:

```
p label{
    float:left;
}
p input{
    float:right;
    margin-right: /*whatever value you need this to be to look good*/;
}
```

here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N4hpQ/32/).

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with Chrome on the Mac, but that fiddle isn't lined up very nicely when I view it.  You might wanna double-check it.

Comment: I think you need to rethink your code, `p` elements can't be splitted into two separate parts just with some CSS. The fiddle looks messy in Win7 and FF too.

Comment: Yes, there is a problem in the JSFiddle example.

Comment: updated jsfiddle, @Marvo and Teemu and Fekula, I am on Linux, so I can't test in IE, but I looked at it in chrome and FF.

Comment: Hard to explain in a comment, but in Mac/Chrome, the LastName field is horizontal with the Country: label, and the LastName: label is oddly indented.  =/